# populate text boxes depend on drop-down selection in php

Tags: javascript, php, drop-down-menu

I research in google and stack overflow for this answer there are lot of answer but i cannot able to get what i want.

I have two drop down menus and three text boxes.

PHP Code :

```
    <select onchange="FirstDropDownClick()"> </select>
```

script code :

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
           function FirstDropDownClick() {

var selectDwn = document.getElementById("ID_dwn");
var selectedValue = selectDwn.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;

                 }
```

In "FirstDropDownClick()" i want the codes for the following :

1.select data from database according to the selected value.

2.Fill the text boxes with that.

3.Fill second drop down according to value of first drop-down menu.

I need an example codes. Because am stuck , dont know how to do .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: put you question in proper format, give html code

Comment: ya, i did that.Hope it remove -1

Comment: not so much still not in proper format, you have to differentiate text and code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your html code

```
    <select name="reg_number" id="reg_number">
       <option value="1">Reg1</option>
       <option value="2">Reg2</option>
       <option value="3">Reg3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
```

your jquery(make sure you include jquery file)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#reg_number').change(function(){
   var reg_number = $(this).val();
   var data_String;
    data_String = 'reg_number='+reg_number;
    $.post('ajax_file.php',data_String,function(data){
          var data= jQuery.parseJSON(data);
           $('#first_name').val(data.first_name)
       });
   });
 });
```

your php code (ajax_file.php)

```
 <?php
       $reg_number =$_POST['reg_number']; 
       //run your query here to fetch the result and store it in a variable $data
     echo json_encode($data);
     exit();`

 ?>
```

Comment: @ Vishal Wadhawan Thanks for your answer. "data_String = 'reg_number='+reg_number;" Whats meaning?

Comment: this is just the key value pair that we send to the php file ie 'reg_number=' is the key and the value reg_number is using the var reg_number = $(this).val();

Comment: In ajax_file.php , is need jqery files? echo "json_encode($data)"; is this correct or not?

Comment: json encode is a php function. will return data in json format. so u can get in in d javascript section using var data= jQuery.parseJSON(data);

Comment: shows an notice; array to string conversion at my sql fetch line.$result=mysqli_query($db, $query);

  $data =  mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $data;
  echo json_encode($data);
exit();

Comment: u hav written echo $data and theen you wrote echo json_encode line.. remove the echo $data line.

Comment: Thanks. $('#first_name').val(data.first_name) in this line data.first_name access what.Because when i echo data , it have array of data.so this data.database field name or output text name?

Comment: ok best would be dont use mysqli_fetch_array(), use mysqli_fetch_assoc()

Comment: this would give you a key and value pair return back. and first_name is the key(field name) in the database

Comment: ya, going fine but the function does not get in to after this line$.post('ajax_file.php',data_String,function(data). The data_sting is needed?Please can you explain what data_string doing?

Comment: data_String is passing the value to the other page.. it is the data which is posted to the php page. and after sucessfully response it goes into $.post('ajax_file.php',data_String,function(data){ 
          var data= jQuery.parseJSON(data); //this section
           $('#first_name').val(data.first_name)
       });

Comment: i think i made some mistakes.:(.  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function(){
 
   $('#agencyID_dwn').change(function(){
     
   var reg_number = $(this).val();
   var data_String;
    data_String = 'reg_number='+reg_number;
    $.post('agency_connectivity.php',data_String,function(data){
          var data= jQuery.parseJSON(data);
  
           $('#testid').val(data.Agency);
  // $('#agencyName_id').val(TEXT);
  
       });
   });
 });

Comment: No because i saved as .js file.But i checked with <script> tag also but did not got result.In php file i give like this if (isset($_POST["lookupSubmit"])) {

$user_id=$_POST['agencyID_dwn'];

$query = "select * from AgencyHome where AgencyName_id = '$user_id'" ;
$result=mysqli_query($db, $query);

  $data =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

  echo json_encode($data);
exit();
 
}

Comment: put a alert inside here like this : $.post('ajax_file.php',data_String,function(data){ alert(data);
          //var data= jQuery.parseJSON(data);
          // $('#first_name').val(data.first_name)
       });

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181389/fill-textbox-when-click-a-button-according-to-dropdown-selection-in-php-jqery        take a look on this link i put my whole codings here.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with ajax and php
HTML

```
<select name="select_number" id="select_number">
    <option value="1">Number1</option>
    <option value="2">Number2</option>
    <option value="3">Number3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="number_value" id="number_value">
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#select_number').change(function(){
        var number_value = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "test.php",
            data: {
                'number_value' : number_value
            },
            dataType:'json',
            success: callback = function(data, textStatus, xhr)
            {
                $('#number_value').val(data.number_value);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

php (test.php)

```
<?php
echo json_encode($_POST);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

why you need php for that you can do it only with jquery or javascript

HTML

```
<select name="select_number" id="select_number">
    <option value="1">Number1</option>
    <option value="2">Number2</option>
    <option value="3">Number3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="number_value" id="number_value">
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#select_number').change(function(){
      var number_value = $(this).val();
      $('#number_value').val(number_value);
    });
});
```

Comment: i tried your code.but did not get output. Include jquery files also.

Comment: got result , missing }); in your code, in jquery file - last line